# Custom Scopes for Spring Cloud Data Flow using Env Variables

Tags: yaml, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-dataflow, scopes

I am attempting to deploy spring-cloud-data-flow-server on cloud foundry, and to use role-mapping to map the default roles to my own scopes.

In order to do so, I'm following https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-security-role-mapping which states **map-oauth-scopes** is to be set to **true** and afterwards all 7 Spring Cloud Data Flow roles should be mapped to scopes.

I've noticed you can configure said properties using the manifest.yml, under the *env* object, with some modifications to the key. As stated in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-docs/src/main/asciidoc/configuration-cloudfoundry.adoc this hierarchy:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      security:
        authorization:
          map-oauth-scopes: true                                    
          role-mappings:
            ROLE_CREATE: dataflow.create                            
            ROLE_DEPLOY: dataflow.deploy
            ROLE_DESTROY: dataflow.destoy
            ROLE_MANAGE: dataflow.manage
            ROLE_MODIFY: dataflow.modify
            ROLE_SCHEDULE: dataflow.schedule
            ROLE_VIEW: dataflow.view
```

Can be represented like so in manifest.yml:

```
- env:
  SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SECURITY_AUTHORIZATION_MAP-OAUTH-SCOPES: true
  SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_SECURITY_AUTHORIZATION_ROLE-MAPPINGS_ROLE_CREATE: <my-scope>
  ...
```

map-oauth-scopes is properly set, however the role mapping isn't. I suspect is has something to do with the underscore in the role prefix (e.g **ROLE_**CREATE), since the 'translation' to the env format requires underscores as hierarchy.

What am I missing? How can I set the role mapping using the manifest.yml?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so not sure if this is how you're suppose to do it, however it works and easily set up.

in the manifest.yml, add a **SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON** entry and pass the mapping as json.

```
applications:
- env:
   ...
    SPRING_PROFILES_DEFAULT: cloud
    SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: |-
        {
           "spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authorization": {
               "map-oauth-scopes": true,                                  
               "role-mappings": {
                  "ROLE_CREATE": "my.scope.for.create",                        
                  "ROLE_DEPLOY": "my.scope.for.deploy",
                  "ROLE_DESTROY": "my.scope.for.destroy",
                  "ROLE_MANAGE": "my.scope.for.manage",
                  "ROLE_MODIFY": "my.scope.for.modify",
                  "ROLE_SCHEDULE": "my.scope.for.schedule",
                  "ROLE_VIEW": "my.scope.for.view"
               }
            }
        }
```

Obviously, scopes can be the same for all roles or differ by role, your choice based on business logic.
Only make sure you login with a user that has the scopes.